# Grouping values based on common attribute

Tags: xml, database, xquery

so far I have this output for an xquery expression:

```
<skill what="C" level="4"/>,
<skill what="C" level="2"/>,
<skill what="C" level="3"/>,
<skill what="Java" level="3"/>,
<skill what="Java" level="3"/>,
<skill what="Java" level="3"/>,
<skill what="SQL" level="2"/>,
<skill what="SQL" level="3"/>,
```

I would like to aggregate the output based on the "what" attribute. So instead of the above I want something like:

```
3, 3, 2
```

Any help on this would certainly be appreciated.

Notes: I am using XML 1.0

Comment: Your XML element all end with comma. What is the original XML you are working with? – Next, you have probably seen that there is a "group by" clause in XQuery. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is because it is the output of the result of the query I ran. I have tried a group by function but that seems to be Xquery 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to produce a count of the number of occurrences of each distinct skill:

If that is the case and you have XQuery 3.0 available to you then you can make use of a `group by` expression, for example:

```
xquery version "3.0";

for $skill in /skill
let $what := string($skill/@what)
group by $what
return
    count($skill)
```

If you don't have XQuery 3.0, but have XQuery 1.0, then you need to first identify the unique skills by `@what` that you wish to group on by using `fn:distinct-values`. From there you can loop over the unique skills, which you can then filter with a predicate, finally determining the minimum skill level. For example:

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $what-skills := distinct-values(/skill/string(@what))
return
    for $what-skill in $what-skills
    let $grouped-skills := /skill[@what eq $what-skill]
    let $count-distinct-skill := count($grouped-skills)
    return
        $count-distinct-skill
```

Comment: I just want to output how many of each "what" there are. For example, since there are 3 elements with the attribute what set to "C", i want to output "3". because there are two elements with the what attribute "SQL", i want to output 2.

Comment: I just modified my answer to provide you with a count rather than the minimum